# Get view controller current scale

Tags: ios, swift3, scale

I've been using the `.transform` method of the `UIViewController.view` property to scaleX and scaleY my view controller.

I've been digging and couldn't find how can I check the current scale state of the VC.

I'm scaling it with:

```
ViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5);
```

Is there any get-property like:

`let currentScale = ViewController.scale` ?

OR

`let scaleX = ViewController.scale.x`

Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;

```
CGFloat xScale = self.view.transform.a;
CGFloat yScale = self.view.transform.d;
```

After applying a scale transform, a transformation will be available through the transform property (CGAffineTransform values) on UIView.

Refer:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform?language=objc